# stackexchange.com search no longer working

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, stackexchange.com, google

When you search the entirety of Stack Exchange from [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/), it displays the following error message:

> Linked CSEs are no longer supported. See https://goo.gl/Gs1KIc.

[Use this link to test it out](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=test).

This leads to instructions which say the following:

> As announced earlier, Linked CSE and Auto CSE and will stop working on May 10th, 2017.
>
> If your site is hosting a Linked CSE configuration or you make a request for search results by specifying a “cref” parameter, then you will need to use the CSE control panel to set your CSE configuration. It may be possible in some cases to upload your XML configuration file via the CSE Context tool found in the CSE control panel under the “Setup” → “Advanced”.
>
> [image: screen shot]
>
> While making this transition, if your page has code that calls “google.search.CustomSearchControl” then you also will need to move to the current API.

Could this please be fixed?

Comment: Someone on SE forgot to read their mail. (Assuming Google sending those announcements in email)

Comment: They do read email @ShadowWizard. It only takes 6 to 8 weeks ...

Comment: As a workaround, https://www.google.com/?q=yoursearchterm+site:stackexchange.com does pretty much the same thing

Comment: @tripleee Except for not including Stack Overflow, Super User, etc...

Comment: True; you'll need to search Ask Ubuntu, Server Fault, etc separately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this up. We indeed missed any communication from Google about this change, and so didn't notice it until you all brought it to our attention. We've updated the way we use Google Custom Search Engine (CSE) to comply with their new APIs. It is now working again. Cheers!